# $\Gamma(x)$ function evaluation

Tags: gamma-function

I'm new to using the Gamma function, $\Gamma(n)$, and I was wondering how I would go about evaluating this, if it is at all possible:

$$
\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha+2)}
$$
This is relating to a specific case I want to find regarding the average luminosity of all galaxies by using the Schechter function. For this case, let's state $\alpha$=-1. For the top case I get infinity, that is to say -1!. I understand that:

$$
\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!
$$

But the top expression is not giving me the answer I expected...

Comment: $\frac 1{\alpha+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gamma function satisfies a recursive property:

$$\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x).$$

In your case, $\Gamma(\alpha+2) = \Gamma((\alpha+1)+1)$ so you are left with $\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$ as the final answer. This assumes that $\alpha+1$ is not a negative integer. In the case that $\alpha$ is a negative integer, your expression is not really well-defined but in the case that $\alpha=-1$, only the numerator is ill-defined (the denominator is perfectly well-defined since $\Gamma(-1+2) = \Gamma(1) = 1$) so it can be interpreted as $\infty$.

Comment: In a word, no. :/ Where do I go from here?

Comment: Actually, in a word, YES! Thank you. Took a while before the penny dropped.

Comment: Glad you got it :)

Comment: No wait, I was wrong. So for $\alpha=-1$?? How is that then evaluated as?

Comment: When $\alpha = -1$, your expression isn't well-defined since $\Gamma(0)$ is not defined, but people often just call it (complex) infinity. See my edit.